# Does bijectivity imply the same order type?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intuition, cardinals

Question: Given an ordered set A which must have bijective correspondences with set B, there must be a correspondence that preserve order?

I know it's wrong. For example, 1.the dictionary order on $\mathbb{Z}_+\times\mathbb{Z}_+$, 2.$(x_0,y_0)<(x_1,y_1)$ if either $x_0+y_0<x_1+y_1$, or $x_0+y_0=x_1+y_1\,and\,y_0<y_1$. They must have bijective correspondence because they have same amount of elements, but are in different order type.

But I feel uncomfortable with that because we all have an intuition that for two groups with same amount of elements( For example, if I can match 1~11, 2~12, 3~13....9~19, 10~20 for sets {1, ... ,10} {11, ... ,20}, I can actually match 1 with 12 with other every elements in {1, ... ,10} matches with elements in {11, ... ,20} ), we can build random correspondence(some correspondence preserves order in this case) between them.

What's wrong with this intuition.

Comment: I do not understand why your 'intuition' collides with the fact you described. The existence of two non-isomorphic ordered sets with the same cardinality simply means ordered sets are not fully determined by its cardinality.

Comment: @HanulJeon It does collide. My intuition is two sets with same cardinality can must build   any bijective correspondence (and one of them preserves order), which is just saying "ordered sets are determined by its cardinality".

Comment: Why do you think that every bijection must preserve every type of structure, though?

Comment: @AsafKaragila For example, if I can match 1~11, 2~12, 3~13....9~19, 10~20 for sets {1, ... ,10} {11, ... ,20}, I can actually match 1 with 12 with other every elements in {1, ... ,10} matches with elements in {11, ... ,20}

Comment: And that preserves the structure given by divisibility, for example?

Answer (score 2):

Everything is wrong with that intuition. In fact, it doesn't work if your sets have more than two elements!

Look at the structure of divisibility, $m\mid n\iff\exists k(k\cdot m=n)$. So for example, $2\mid 4$ and $4\mid 8$, but $4\nmid 3$. Then $\{1,\dots,10\}$ with $|$ is **very** different from $\{11,\dots,20\}$ with $|$. The latter is an antichain, whereas the former has nontrivial comparisons (as we pointed out: $1\mid 2\mid 4\mid 8$).

But you might want to say, I didn't sign up for preserving divisibility. I only wanted to preserve a linear order! But that's the point. Bijections don't have to preserve any "natural structure".

For that matter, setting $f\colon\{0,1\}\to\{2,3\}$ by $f(0)=3$ and $f(1)=2$ also **does not preserve the order**. It flips it. Of course those two are isomorphic, and you could argue there that that's fine. But that only means that a function $f\colon\Bbb{Z\to N}$ needs to be an isomorphism with respect to **some** structure, not *all* structure. And that's true, given any bijection from $X$ to $Y$ we can use it to define a structure on $X$ (or on $Y$) such that $f$ is an isomorphism.

And I mean, what's the order on $\{x,y\}$ when I only tell you that $x\neq y$? Did I tell you what are these objects and how they relate to each other? Not all orders are linear.

---

Remember: almost any naive intuition that you're coming with is wrong, in almost any field of mathematics. That is why we have definitions. Work with the definitions, step by step, and very very carefully, and you'll develop the correct definitions.

Or to quote John von Neumann, "in mathematics you don't understand things, you just get used to them."

Comment: "setting $f:\{0,1\}\to\{2,3\}$ by $f(0)=3$ and $f(1)=2$ also does not preserve the order." Yes, but OP is asking whether or not *an order-preserving map exists*, which it clearly does between finite sets of the same cardinality.

Comment: Yes, I can read the question. I'm pointing out that bijections don't have to preserve things. Not the actual order, not an order which doesn't exist, and in general, not any structure.

Comment: Thank for your work, I have read your answer many times. but I think your answer is not straightforward. For the 2nd paragraph, it's helpless because the two sets are not in the same structure, but I'm saying two sets all with order(same structure). You only discuss the relevant in the 3nd paragraph,  where you just repeat the truth. and what I want may be some definite fact telling why I can not build such an bijection preserving order.

Comment: @CHENWONG: If you are not open to hearing experts, why are you asking a question? You keep saying that this is wrong, but it's not. You provide no reason for it to be wrong, you just say that you feel that it should be wrong. Well, you are wrong.

Comment: I’m not saying this is wrong, in fact I think you are true . Em.. maybe It’s my fault, I didn’t make it clear what I want or I’m not clear about the question myself . Anyway thanks for your patient!

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are bijective but there's no order-preserving map between them. Loosely speaking, this is to do with the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ has a starting number, but $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't.

$\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are bijective but there's no order-preserving map between them. This has to do with $\mathbb{Q}$ being dense, whereas $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't.

Some sets of cardinality $|\mathbb{R}|$ also have same property: I don't think there is an order-preserving map between $f: [-1,0] \cup [1,2] \to [0,1]$ because $f(0) < f(1)$, which means that for  $f(0) < b < f(1)$ there is no $a \in [-1,0] \cup [1,2]$ such that $f(a) = b$.

I'm not sure how to characterise all these results, but I'm sure it can be done.

Anyway, hopefully I have shown that it is clear that your intuition that "Given an ordered set $A$ which is bijective to set $B$, there must be a correspondence that preserves order" is incorrect. I understand *why* you have this intuition, but if it's incorrect then it's incorrect.

Comment: What distinguishes the orders $[-1,0]\cup[1,2]$ and $[0,1]$ is that the former has a point with an immediate successor, and the latter has no such point.

Comment: That makes sense. I also found this which seems relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2545910/prob-7-a-sec-24-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-any-order-preserving-surject